# “can't convert from BSON type String to Date” MongoDB for Java 3.5

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here the query in Bson :

```
var match = {


$match : {

    "dt_extract": {
    "$gte": new ISODate("2016-12-05T13:29:28.737+01:00"),
    "$lte": new ISODate("2017-12-11T13:29:29.929+01:00")
  }

}


}


var group = {

$group :{
        "_id":{
                weekNum : {"$isoWeek" :"$dt_extract"} ,
                year :{"$isoWeekYear": "$dt_extract"},
                dt_extract_date: "$dt_extract"
        },

        "Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator":{
        "$sum":"$mlf16_txfiabnum"   
        }

}
}

var project = {


$project: { 

    "Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator":1
}


}

var sort = {
    $sort :{_id : -1}
}


 db.mplf_tmp_v3.aggregate([match,group,project,sort])
```

this request work and i didn't have any problem but when i want to write it in Mongo for Java 3.5 i got the problem to convert Bson type String to Date .

```
private List<Bson> filtersQueryCard(QueryParamWarningDto queryParamWarningDto) {

        List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<>();

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

        Date date = new Date() ;

        DateTimeFormatter sdf1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");


        localDate = LocalDate.parse(localDate.toString(), sdf1);

        LocalDate localDateMin = localDate.minusWeeks(53);


        LocalDate localDateMax = localDate;


        DateTime dateTimeMin = localDateMin.toDateTimeAtCurrentTime();
        DateTime dateTimeMax = localDateMax.toDateTimeAtCurrentTime();



        if (queryParamWarningDto.getIdRefNum() != null) {

            filters.add(eq(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_CODRAFT.getLabel(), queryParamWarningDto.getIdRefNum()));
            filters.add(gte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel(), "new ISODate('"+dateTimeMin.toString()+"')"));
            filters.add(lte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel(),"new ISODate('"+dateTimeMax.toString()+"')"));

        } else {
            filters.add(eq(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_CPTFOU_SIX.getLabel(), queryParamWarningDto.getIdSupNum()));
            filters.add(eq(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_CODADRES.getLabel(), queryParamWarningDto.getCodeSuppNum()));

            filters.add(gte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel(),"new ISODate('"+dateTimeMin.toString()+"')"));
            filters.add(lte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel(),"new ISODate('"+dateTimeMax.toString()+"')"));
        }
        return filters;
    }


private List<SupplierIndicatorDTOM> getAllIndicatorForSupp(QueryParamWarningDto queryParamWarningDto) {

        List<SupplierIndicatorDTOM> results = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Bson> filters = filtersQueryCard(queryParamWarningDto);

        MongoDatabase database = mongoUtil.mongoClient();

        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("mplf_tmp_v3");


        try {

            AggregateIterable<Document> resultMongo = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                    Aggregates.match(and(filters)),
                    Aggregates.group(and(eq("weekNum", eq("$isoWeek", "$dt_extract"))
                            , eq("year", eq("$isoWeekYear","$dt_extract")),
                            eq("dt_extract_date", "$dt_extract"),
                            eq(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXFIABNUM.getLabel(), SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXFIABNUM.getLabel()),
                            eq(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXFIABDEN.getLabel(), SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXFIABDEN.getLabel())
                            ), Accumulators.sum("Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator", SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXFIABNUM.getLabel())
                            , Accumulators.sum("Sum_Reliability_Rate_Denominator", SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXFIABDEN.getLabel())
                            , Accumulators.sum("Sum_Doc_Rate_Numerator", SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXDOCNUM.getLabel())
                            , Accumulators.sum("Sum_Doc_Rate_Denominator", SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXDOCDEN.getLabel())
                            , Accumulators.sum("Sum_Service_Rate_Numerator", SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXSERVNUM.getLabel())
                            , Accumulators.sum("Sum_Service_Rate_Denominator", SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.MLF16_TXSERVDEN.getLabel())),
                    Aggregates.project(include("Sum_Reliability_Rate_Numerator", "Sum_Reliability_Rate_Denominator", "Sum_Doc_Rate_Numerator"
                            , "Sum_Doc_Rate_Denominator", "Sum_Service_Rate_Numerator", "Sum_Service_Rate_Denominator"))));
```

Comment: ISODate is a mongo shell type not a java type.  Pass the DateTime variable instead

Comment: @Veeram i passed but it didn't work !!

Comment: @Veeram i did this it work   
  filters.add(gte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel(),"new ISODate('"+dateTimeMin.toString()+"')"));
            filters.add(lte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel(),"new ISODate('"+dateTimeMax.toString()+"')"));

Comment: This is incorrect. Correct version `filters.add(gte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLab‌​el(),dateTimeMin)); filters.add(lte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLab‌​el(),dateTimeMax));`

Comment: @Veeram i have a new error after your version : org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.joda.time.DateTime.

Comment: That makes sense as joda data types are not supported in mongo driver. Convert them over to java.util.Date  i.e.  `dateTimeMin.toDate()` and `dateTimeMax.toDate()` in your query.

Comment: @Veeram i got a new error  :com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16006: 'can't convert from BSON type string to Date'

Comment: The error occurs when you use $iso operators on string version of date. Do you have dates stored in both string and date type in db ? Verify if all the dates are stored as date types.

Comment: Yes my dates are stored as Date Type

Comment: Here an exemple of dt_extract in my DB : 2017-05-14 00:00:00.000

Comment: Not sure what could be the problem then. Make sure you are creating the filters correctly. Just for clarity. Use `filters.add(gte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLab‌​‌​el(),dateTimeMin.toDate()))‌​; filters.add(lte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLab‌​‌​el(),dateTimeMax.toDate()))‌​;`. Try running the query without match stage and see if it works.

Comment: @Veeram you are right . I try to make the query without match and i got the some Error

Comment: @Veeram i think the problem is for $isoWeek : here  { `Aggregates.group(and(eq("weekNum", eq("$isoWeek", SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel()))
                            , eq("year", eq("$isoWeekYear",SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel())),
                            eq("dt_extract_date", SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel())`

Comment: You are missing `$` in your query.  Try `"$" + SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel()`.

Comment: @Veeram thanks :) it worked after i add "$"

Comment: @Veeram can you please make the solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing issues from posted comments.

`ISODate` is a shell type. You need to use `java.util.Date` type when passing the criteria values to filters

Convert the jodatime to Date using `DateTime.toDate()`

`filters.add(gte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLab‌​‌​‌​el(),dateTimeMin‌​.toDate()))‌​; filters.add(lte(SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLab‌​‌​‌​el(),dateTimeMax‌​.toDate()))‌​;`

Include `$` in the constants to evaluate the string as variable in  mongodb.

`and(eq("weekNum", eq("$isoWeek", "$" + SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel())) , eq("year", eq("$isoWeekYear","$" + SupplierIndicatorFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getL‌​abel())`